# How to create form to select player among many teams?

Tags: cognito-forms

I'd like to build a form that allows a user to first select a team (from among about 100 teams) and then select a player from that team.

I think it can be done with conditional logic and adding many entries, manually, but if someone has done this before, is there any easy way?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the easiest thing to do is to simply add a Choice field with a list of teams, and then create a Choice field with each team's roster that appears when the corresponding team is selected using the Show This Field option:

[image]

The Choice field allows for bulk choice importing, so you can copy a list from Notepad, Word, Excel, or the web and paste it into the first line in the Choice field editor to bulk create list choices. Each line item will populate into the list down, eliminating the need to manually copy every item from long lists.